# Read selected mail office 365 via C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, office365, office365api

How can I read selected mail and get document(s) in (office 365) from my application?
I'm using visual studio 2015 express.

Comment: Is this a web Mail Addin project?

Comment: Actually we are using Outlook for work computer but also we can have an access for office365 mail. Also office version is office 365 proplus. Actually  really it doenst matter where (outlook or web) can i read mail it is ok for me.

Answer (score 0):

For a desktop COM Add-in, you can access the selected email(s) via the Explorer.Selection property: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ff861267.aspx. Then just cast the item(s) to the appropriate object class (e.g. MailItem).

For a web Mail Add-in, your addin code would already have intrinsic access to the active message via the Office.context.mailbox.item object: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/fp142177.aspx